# Autoware Launching?

Tags: ros, ros-melodic

[image: Rosanswers logo]

Operating system and version:
Ubuntu 18.04
gcc (Ubuntu 7.4.0-1ubuntu1~18.04.1) 7.4.0
cmake version 3.10.2

Autoware installation type
Built from source-1.12.0-alpha2([link text](https://gitlab.com/autowarefoundation/autoware.ai/autoware/wikis/Source-Build))

ROS distribution:
melodic
ROS installation type:
sudo apt-get install ros-melodic-desktop-full

git status:

```
~/autoware.ai$ git status
fatal: not a git repository (or any of the parent directories): .git

~/autoware.ai$ git rev-parse HEAD
fatal: not a git repository (or any of the parent directories): .git
```

HI, I was able to install Autoware and Colcon build was successful. But I am unable to launch autoware, I tried to run a demo by following this link [link text](https://gitlab.com/autowarefoundation/autoware.ai/autoware/wikis/ROSBAG-Demo).

When I used last time there is one directory ~/Autoware/ros but now there is no such directory inside my autoware.ai workspace. I think that 1.12.0-alpha2 is not committed but from the source page, I think we can install 1.12.0-alpha2 and run autoware by ./run this command.

I think that do they need to commit? Correct me if I am wrong. Thanks

Any help is appreciated in launching autoware??

When I sourced it I am getting this output

```
~/autoware.ai/install/setup.bash 
not found: "/home/am97/autoware.ai/install/adi_driver
autoware_bag_tools
autoware_build_flags
autoware_can_msgs
autoware_config_msgs
autoware_driveworks_gmsl_interface
autoware_external_msgs
autoware_launcher
autoware_launcher_rviz
autoware_map_msgs
autoware_msgs
amathutils_lib
as
astar_search
autoware_camera_lidar_calibrator
autoware_connector
autoware_driveworks_interface
autoware_pointgrey_drivers
autoware_rviz_plugins
autoware_system_msgs
autoware_health_checker
calibration_publisher
citysim
custom_msgs
data_preprocessor
decision_maker_panel
detected_objects_visualizer
ds4_driver
ds4_msgs
ds4
ekf_localizer
fastvirtualscan
freespace_planner
garmin
gazebo_camera_description
gazebo_imu_description
gazebo_world_description
glviewer
gnss
gnss_localizer
graph_tools
hokuyo
image_processor
integrated_viewer
javad_navsat_driver
kitti_box_publisher
kitti_player
kitti_launch
kvaser
lgsvl_simulator_bridge
lidar_apollo_cnn_seg_detect
lidar_fake_perception
lidar_naive_l_shape_detect
lidar_point_pillars
lidar_shape_estimation
log_tools
map_tf_generator
map_tools
marker_downsampler
memsic_imu
microstrain_driver
multi_lidar_calibrator
ndt_cpu
ndt_gpu
ndt_tku
nmea_navsat
obj_db
oculus_socket
pc2_downsampler
pcl_omp_registration
lidar_localizer
pixel_cloud_fusion
points_downsampler
points_preprocessor
pos_db
range_vision_fusion
roi_object_filter
rosbag_controller
rosinterface
points2image
sick_ldmrs_description
sick_ldmrs_msgs
sick_ldmrs_driver
sick_ldmrs_tools
sick_ldmrs_laser
sick_lms5xx
sound_player
state_machine_lib
tablet_socket_msgs
mqtt_socket
runtime_manager
tablet_socket
twist_generator
udon_socket
vectacam
vector_map_msgs
vector_map
decision_maker
imm_ukf_pda_track
libvectormap
map_file
naive_motion_predict
object_map
costmap_generator
road_occupancy_processor
vector_map_server
lidar_euclidean_cluster_detect
op_utility
op_planner
op_simu
trafficlight_recognizer
vehicle_description
vehicle_gazebo_simulation_interface
vehicle_gazebo_simulation_launcher
vehicle_model
vehicle_socket
vision_beyond_track
vision_darknet_detect
vision_lane_detect
vision_segment_enet_detect
vision_ssd_detect
vlg22c_cam
waypoint_follower
dp_planner
ff_waypoint_follower
lane_planner
op_ros_helpers
lidar_kf_contour_track
op_global_planner
op_local_planner
op_simulation_package
op_utilities
way_planner
waypoint_maker
waypoint_planner
lattice_planner
xsens_driver
ymc/share/adi_driver
autoware_bag_tools
autoware_build_flags
autoware_can_msgs
autoware_config_msgs
autoware_driveworks_gmsl_interface
autoware_external_msgs
autoware_launcher
autoware_launcher_rviz
autoware_map_msgs
autoware_msgs
amathutils_lib
as
astar_search
autoware_camera_lidar_calibrator
autoware_connector
autoware_driveworks_interface
autoware_pointgrey_drivers
autoware_rviz_plugins
autoware_system_msgs
autoware_health_checker
calibration_publisher
citysim
custom_msgs
data_preprocessor
decision_maker_panel
detected_objects_visualizer
ds4_driver
ds4_msgs
ds4
ekf_localizer
fastvirtualscan
freespace_planner
garmin
gazebo_camera_description
gazebo_imu_description
gazebo_world_description
glviewer
gnss
gnss_localizer
graph_tools
hokuyo
image_processor
integrated_viewer
javad_navsat_driver
kitti_box_publisher
kitti_player
kitti_launch
kvaser
lgsvl_simulator_bridge
lidar_apollo_cnn_seg_detect
lidar_fake_perception
lidar_naive_l_shape_detect
lidar_point_pillars
lidar_shape_estimation
log_tools
map_tf_generator
map_tools
marker_downsampler
memsic_imu
microstrain_driver
multi_lidar_calibrator
ndt_cpu
ndt_gpu
ndt_tku
nmea_navsat
obj_db
oculus_socket
pc2_downsampler
pcl_omp_registration
lidar_localizer
pixel_cloud_fusion
points_downsampler
points_preprocessor
pos_db
range_vision_fusion
roi_object_filter
rosbag_controller
rosinterface
points2image
sick_ldmrs_description
sick_ldmrs_msgs
sick_ldmrs_driver
sick_ldmrs_tools
sick_ldmrs_laser
sick_lms5xx
sound_player
state_machine_lib
tablet_socket_msgs
mqtt_socket
runtime_manager
tablet_socket
twist_generator
udon_socket
vectacam
vector_map_msgs
vector_map
decision_maker
imm_ukf_pda_track
libvectormap
map_file
naive_motion_predict
object_map
costmap_generator
road_occupancy_processor
vector_map_server
lidar_euclidean_cluster_detect
op_utility
op_planner
op_simu
trafficlight_recognizer
vehicle_description
vehicle_gazebo_simulation_interface
vehicle_gazebo_simulation_launcher
vehicle_model
vehicle_socket
vision_beyond_track
vision_darknet_detect
vision_lane_detect
vision_segment_enet_detect
vision_ssd_detect
vlg22c_cam
waypoint_follower
dp_planner
ff_waypoint_follower
lane_planner
op_ros_helpers
lidar_kf_contour_track
op_global_planner
op_local_planner
op_simulation_package
op_utilities
way_planner
waypoint_maker
waypoint_planner
lattice_planner
xsens_driver
ymc/package.bash"
```

---

[Originally posted](https://answers.ros.org/question/327290/autoware-launching??/) by [AM97](https://answers.ros.org/users/41623/am97/) on ROS Answers with karma: 139 on 2019-06-28

Post score: 1

---

#### Original comments

**Comment by [AM97](https://answers.ros.org/users/41623/am97/) on 2019-06-29**:
I already checked and i sourced it

```
~/autoware.ai$ source ~/autoware.ai/install/setup.bash
not found: "/home/sai/autoware.ai/install/adi_driver
autoware_bag_tools
autoware_build_flags
autoware_can_msgs
autoware_config_msgs
autoware_driveworks_gmsl_interface
autoware_external_msgs
autoware_launcher
autoware_launcher_rviz
autoware_map_msgs
autoware_msgs
amathutils_lib
as
astar_search
autoware_camera_lidar_calibrator
autoware_connector
autoware_driveworks_interface
autoware_pointgrey_drivers
autoware_rviz_plugins
autoware_system_msgs
autoware_health_checker
calibration_publisher
citysim
custom_msgs
data_preprocessor
decision_maker_panel
detected_objects_visualizer
ds4_driver
ds4_msgs
ds4
ekf_localizer
fastvirtualscan
freespace_planner
garmin
gazebo_camera_description
gazebo_imu_description
gazebo_world_description
glviewer
gnss
gnss_localizer
graph_tools
hokuyo
image_processor
integrated_viewer
javad_navsat_driver
kitti_box_publisher
kitti_player
kitti_launch
kvaser
lgsvl_simulator_bridge
```

Answer (score 0, accepted):

[image: Rosanswers logo]

@sm94 - The convenience scripts have been moved to a new location. They are now in the runtime_manager package which, if you followed the instructions for the 1.12.0-alpha.2 install, should be under ~/autoware.ai/src/autoware/utilities/runtime_manager/ (see the scripts folder).

Once you have built Autoware and sourced the `~/autoware.ai/install/setup.bash` file, you should also be able to run it with:

```
rosrun runtime_manager run
```

***Edit***: I made a mistake - the change to move the convenience scripts to the `runtime_manager` package did not happen until *after* the 1.12.0-alpha.2 release. Because of this, I have updated the build instructions. See https://gitlab.com/autowarefoundation/autoware.ai/autoware/wikis/Source-Build#for-1120-alpha2 for the new instructions. The run script will be under `$HOME/autoware/ros` after the build. Sorry for the confusion.

---

Originally posted by [Josh Whitley](https://answers.ros.org/users/4390/josh-whitley/) with karma: 1766 on 2019-06-28

This answer was **ACCEPTED** on the original site

Post score: 0

---

#### Original comments

**Comment by [AM97](https://answers.ros.org/users/41623/am97/) on 2019-06-28**:
@Maximus I already tried this but I am getting the same error
rosrun runtime_manager run
[rosrun] Couldn't find executable named run below /home/sai/autoware.ai/install/runtime_manager/share/runtime_manager

I have rechecked and I already sourced ~/autoware.ai/install/setup.bash.

**Comment by [soroosh129](https://answers.ros.org/users/30568/soroosh129/) on 2019-06-28**:
I am guessing your setup.bash doesn't finish properly. Can you double check the output of "source ~/autoware.ai/install/setup.bash"?

**Comment by [AM97](https://answers.ros.org/users/41623/am97/) on 2019-06-29**:
@soroosh129 Actually I have rechecked and modified the question and added what was the output when i sourced it

**Comment by [soroosh129](https://answers.ros.org/users/30568/soroosh129/) on 2019-06-29**:
@AM97 Yup that is an error. Try using catkin_make instead. Then the setup.bash will be in devel/ instead of install/ .

**Comment by [AM97](https://answers.ros.org/users/41623/am97/) on 2019-06-30**:
@soroosh129 I used catkin build  and the setup.bash was in devel but I am getting the same error

Here is the output of terminal:

```
~/autoware.ai$ source devel/setup.bash

~/autoware.ai/src/autoware/utilities/runtime_manager/scripts$ rosrun runtime_manager run
[rosrun] Couldn't find executable named run below /home/sai/autoware.ai/src/autoware/utilities/runtime_manager
```

**Comment by [Josh Whitley](https://answers.ros.org/users/4390/josh-whitley/) on 2019-06-30**:
The document for the demo is out of date. For 1.11.0 and above, only `colcon` is supported,  not `catkin`. Please delete the `devel`, `build`, and `install` folders in your `autoware.ai` folder and re-build the workspace with `colcon build`. Verify that the build competes successfully with 0 failed packages. Open a brand new terminal and `source ~/autoware.ai/install/setup.bash`. If the command `rosrun runtime_manager run` doesn't work, then you may need to `cd` to `~/autoware.ai/src/autoware/utilities/runtime_manager/scripts` and run the script manually with `./run`.

**Comment by [AM97](https://answers.ros.org/users/41623/am97/) on 2019-06-30**:
@Maximus5684 I tried but I am unable to launch, I did colcon build by deleting all devel, build, and install folders.

```
~/autoware.ai$ source ~/autoware.ai/install/setup.bash 
~/autoware.ai$ rosrun runtime_manager run
[rosrun] Couldn't find executable named run below /home/sai/autoware.ai/install/runtime_manager/share/runtime_manager
:~/autoware.ai/src/autoware/utilities/runtime_manager/scripts$ ./run
bash: ./run: No such file or directory

Summary: 138 packages finished [16min 6s]
  47 packages had stderr output: adi_driver astar_search autoware_camera_lidar_calibrator autoware_connector autoware_driveworks_gmsl_interface autoware_driveworks_interface autoware_pointgrey_drivers citysim data_preprocessor decision_maker dp_planner gazebo_world_description glviewer kitti_player kvaser lidar_apollo_cnn_seg_detect lidar_euclidean_cluster_detect lidar_localizer lidar_point_pillars lidar_shape_estimation map_file microstrain_driver mqtt_socket ndt_cpu ndt_gpu object_map op_ros_helpers op_
```

**Comment by [Josh Whitley](https://answers.ros.org/users/4390/josh-whitley/) on 2019-07-01**:
@AM97 / @soroosh129 - Please see my edit to my response above.

**Comment by [AM97](https://answers.ros.org/users/41623/am97/) on 2019-07-01**:
@Maximus5684 Its working now. Thanks